# TSdoc for functions in interfaces

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code, tsdoc

I am having issues with documenting my functions when they come from interfaces. (This is a react app)

here's a visual example of my problem:

```js
export interface IUserContext {
  /**
   * The call signature for `OnLeave`.
   * @param success - true if successful
   */
  onLeave: (success: boolean) => Promise<unknown>;
}
```

this is a somewhat basic and easy interface with some documentation for my function.

When creating my reacte context, I do it like this:

```js
export const UserContext = React.createContext<IUserContext | null>(null);
```

If you have a look on the picture below, you can see that upon calling that function in another file from my context, the tsdoc does not correspond.[image]

@param is missing. When trying with other tagsn none of them appear...

Anyone knows what is going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my own question after all.

The problem comes from destructuring the returned value from the "useUser" context.
I still have to look up a bit more to understand why. But if you stumble upon the same problem, do not destructure the returned value and everything is going to be ok :-)